# Clone depth on AWS Pipeline

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, cypress, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to send git repo metadata along to the cypress dashboard for end to end testing. This testing is triggered with AWS CodePipeline.

According to Amazon's documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-github-gitclone.html) one should be able to select the clone depth while setting up the CodePipeline. Though when I am at that stage in the tutorial there is no option as only repository and branch are listed.

The batch build uses the source from the pipeline when the pipeline is triggered (manually or by webhook) but no git repo metadata is received.

In the CodeBuild used in the pipeline the clone depth option is set to full. When the CodeBuild is triggered manually the metadata is available and sent to Cypress dashboard.

Is it something simple I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

In the `Add source stage` step of creating a CodePipeline, where you also specify the repository and branch, you can choose between a `CodePipeline default` option and doing a `Full clone`. While the default option does not include Git metadata (which basically means that the Git clone depth is `1`), opting for a full clone should provide you with the required Git metadata and commit history in the CodeBuild stage:

[image]

Comment: Great answer and it is there plain as day and impossible to miss... If you are using v2 or above of the github connection type. That was my problem as I was using v1.